# Best method for generating documents/reports in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, report, document

I’m looking at options to send user input data from my application (mainly strings and doubles) into a stylised document (such as a quotation or invoice)

I have done quite a bit of research however am even more confused in which method would suit me best, so am looking for some input, as which direction to go, I have found some of the following options:

- **Crystal Reports** - although I think this is more for reporting data from SQL databases, not to mention it looks as though people struggle with running there applications in different environments on different machines.
- **MajorSilence Reporting (formerly FyiReporting)** - a Crystal Report alternative that’s open source so would alleviate a lot of problems again though I think it’s for databases and hasn’t been worked on since2015
- **Word Or Excel Document** - Seems I would have to have a template file of some sort and I did want to control as much as I could in program not to mention it just seems kind of unprofessional in a way when used by other users at my work.
- **PrintForm** - where I print direct from a form in the application while hiding the buttons but this may be hard to do over two pages.

If anyone has any input on the above or new ideas or even if I’m on the correct track to how this is usually done, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Just wondering what is "unprofessional" about the 3rd option? I believe that is the most common way, use a template document and feature like "mail merge" or "find & replace" to generate a resulting document(s).

Comment: @MarioZ On further research i was thinking i will go with the 3rd option, my original concern was that not everyone has Office installed, but hopefully i can figure out a way that once data is populated in Excel ill publish or convert it to a .pdf file so the user never sees the editable version of the document, Thank you for your input.

Comment: There are solutions that don't require having MS Office installed. For instance, see [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document) and its [mail merge](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-mail-merge-word/901) example.